# How to get Order Information (phone number) on sales_order_place_after event

Tags: magento

I've cteated a custom module for my Magento 1.7.02 using "sales_order_place_after" event
I need to get Order Increment Id and the Phone number of the order address
I know how to get the Order Increment id:

> $incrementid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();

But how do I get the phone number ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The complete order object is passed to the `sales_order_place_after` event, so you can get any property of the order object in this event observer, the same as you would anywhere else in Magento.

```
$incrementId = $observer->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
$phone = $observer->getOrder()->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

Comment: Thank you Jim very much. It was exactly like that. I didn't really knew that you can get the info exactly the same as anywhere else on magento. Thank you once again.

Comment: Hi Dan! Magento passes a complete model object to most of it's events, so sales related events will generally receive a full quote and/or order object, product events (e.g. before save or after save) receive a complete product object.  It makes Magento's event system extremely powerful.